# How can I stop my ec2 server from crashing when I use the "Remote - SSH" extension?

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2, vscode-remote-ssh

Every time I connect to my ec2 server with Microsoft's "Remote - SSH" VSCode extention it crashes my server and I have to manually goto the AWS console and stop/start the instance. Is there any way to fix this? I am also using venv, if that has anything to do with it. When it disconnects it gives no errors and it just says "Setting up SSH Host [server ip].

Server Tier: t2.micro

Server OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Python 3.10.4

Comment: Does not look related to python or ubuntu.

Comment: Can this help? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_ssh-host-setup

Comment: This is the issue of VSCode which has been left for 2 years. 
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2692

Comment: I don't have a remote server, but a ras pi 4. It got the same problem, connect via ssh remote ext, debug my project a few times, and then it disconnected from the server. And I can't even ssh using cmd. A potential solution for my case is set up a script to restart ssh service + remove ~/.vscode-server/bin every minute. It been fine for 2 days now.